# Xcode 4.2 doesn't show some supporting files in sidebar

Tags: ios, xcode, file, xcode4.2

I am experiencing a problem with XCode and my supporting files.  There are several images that I am trying to replace with newer versions (same filename), and although the files are definitely accessible to my project (they display when used in the app), they aren't visible in the Navigator tab on the left, nor can I find them in the project folder in my documents. When I try to drag in the newest versions, it says that the file already exists.  Is there a way to refresh the Navigator to show all of my files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible that you have placed them in another folder by mistake? Did you try searching for the images on your computer? When you find the files, copy the images to the resources folder of the project or wherever you want them to be. Do this first on your computer. Then, drag and drop them into xcode. Let me know if it works.

Comment: You were right, they ended up in a strange folder within the project directory.  It just took deleting those and dragging them back into XCode to resolve the issue.